# Python struct.unpack byte length issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, byte, endianness

I have the following code:

```
msg = b'0,[\x00\x01\x86\xec\x96N'
print(struct.unpack("<"+"I",msg))
```

however everytime i try to do this it says

*struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes*

What i tried to do is the following

```
times = int(len(msg)/4)
 struct.unpack("<"+"I" * times,msg)
```

but it doesnt always work, i think on uneven numbers, how can i get the correct size so i dont encounter these issues?

Answer (score 0):

`struct.unpack` requires that the length of the buffer being consumed is *exactly* the size of the format. [1]

Use `struct.unpack_from` instead, which requires that the length of the buffer being consumed is *at least* the size of the format. [2]

```py
>>> msg = b'0,[\x00\x01\x86\xec\x96N'

>>> import struct
>>> print(struct.unpack("<"+"I", msg))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

>>> print(struct.unpack_from("<"+"I", msg))
(5975088,)
```

Additional bytes will be ignored by `unpack_from`

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack
[2] https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from